# Voice Listen API in background using more battery

Tags: android, background, listener, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am developing a app in android which listens to voice all the time in background. i am using SpeechRecognizer offline api . please can any body tell me any best option . My code is :

```
 public void raise() {
    try {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                offSound();
                speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
                listener = new MyRecognitionListener();
                speech.setRecognitionListener(listener);
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, SharedPreferenceWriter.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getString(SPreferenceKey.SELECTED_LANGUAGE));
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getApplication().getPackageName());

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 1000);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 1000);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 1000);

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, true);
enter code here
                speech.startListening(intent);

                /*
                 * if (countPrintLog++ > 150) { countPrintLog = 0;
                 * LogManager
                 * .getInstance().writeToLog(LogManager.LOG_STORAGE_FILE,
                 * "Speech Recogniser is working"); }
                 */
                Log.i("", "Calling the Recognise");

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class MyRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        onSound();
        Log.i("", "onError");
        isCriticalSectionRaise = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {



    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

    }

}
```

This consumes a lot of battery resource and heats the device. I'm looking for a better option

Comment: Motorola "X" phones (Droid Ultra, Moto X, Droid MAXX) have a dedicated speech recognition chip which is always on, and always works. However, it's not accessible to mere mortals, and may only have a limited capacity for phrase recognition. I don't think you can do what you want to do any other way -- unless you figure out a way to keep the SR off until some other sensor input (i.e. light sensor) tells you to turn it on.

Comment: Do we need to write some specific code for Motorola "X" phones (Droid Ultra, Moto X, Droid MAXX) for voice recognition or same code will be workable .

Comment: I do not believe that the Moto X hardware is accessible to app developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large vocabulary speech recognition requires quite a lot of resources, you need to use special solution to listen continuously.

If you are interested, take a look on CMUSphinx on Android

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Demo above can listen for keyword "oh mighty computer" efficiently, you can configure the keyword and detection threshold. On our experiment the listening takes less resources than screen and the battery easily lasts whole day.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay Shmyrev for this beautiful solution. Can we set a specific word using this api so that when user speck that specific word ... app will raise music .

Comment: Yes, you can configure arbitrary keyword. For the best detection accuracy keyword should have 4-5 syllables.

Comment: You can see the short code sample here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463721/keyword-is-not-detected-using-pocketsphinx-on-android/24463965#24463965

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now it is giving right answer to me in onResult . But if i set hello in KEYPHASE and try to speak Lock or other word but it always give me Result "Hello"

Comment: You need to tune threshold to avoid false detections (see the link). Hello is too short, you need longer phrase like "Hello Conrad".

Comment: If i set "Hello Conrad" KEYPHASE  then app crashed. Saying unable to decode . How we can set any word and app can response for all .

Comment: Case matters so keyphrase must be in lowercase "hello conrad". There must be errors about missing words in the logcat which you can check.

Comment: Nice this is working perfect .... please tell few points 1 - can it will listen all the time in background if i put in android service , 2- Can it will response for every word without internet . 3- can you work for us (Add me on skype sachin.auxiliumit).

Comment: Ok, great, you can add me in skype if you have questions, my id is nv_shmyrev.

Comment: Hi sir ... i have one error when i am using "Chilli" as a KEYPHRASE. ERROR: "kws_search.c", line 158: The word 'chilli' is missing in the dictionary ... please help .